# Definition of Associated Bundle of a Principal Bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a principal $G$-bundle $\pi : P \to X$ and another space $F$, then to each continuous homomorphism $\rho : G \to Homeo(F)$, the associated bundle $\pi_{\rho}: P \times_{\rho} F \to X$ is constructed by taking the product $P \times F$ modulo the orbits of the free left action of $G$ on $P \times F$ given by $\phi_g(p,f) = (pg^{-1},\rho (g)f)$.

I don't understand where the action $(pg^{-1},\rho (g)f)$ is coming from. The definition in general feels very arbitrary, and the source I am looking at doesn't give any motivation for it. I would like to know why and how we get this action  in particular.

Comment: Have you tried to understand the most basic examples? Consider a trivial vector bundle $X\times \Bbb R^k$ and the principal frame bundle (so $G=O(k)$ or $GL(k)$). $\rho$ will be the standard left regular representation $\rho(g)v = gv$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking me to consider since the definition involves a principal bundle and homeomorphisms of a space, and you're giving me two bundles (the total space?). If I take the principal frame bundle with structure group $G = GL(k)$ as P and $F = \Bbb R^k$, then I believe I should get something isomorphic to the tangent bundle on X via the map which sends $(p,x)$ to $p(x)$. I'm still not sure what the general purpose of the definition is, though.

Comment: You have pairs $(p,f)$, with $G$ acting by the right on $P$ and by the left on $f$ (via $\rho$), meaning that we can look at $(pg,f)$ and $(p, \rho(g)f)$ (omitting $\rho$ from the notation, think of $(p,gf)$ instead). We'd like to consider those pairs the same (in the quotient). The action that does this service is $((p,f),g) \mapsto (pg, \rho(g^{-1})f)$. In other words, we may operate as if $g$ and $\rho(g^{-1})$ "cancel each other" in the quotient.

Comment: @IvoTerek Write that up as an answer...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Alright, converted to an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to an answer:

You have pairs $(p,f)$, with $G$ acting by the right on $P$ and by the left on $f$ (via $\rho$), meaning that we can look at $(pg,f)$ and $(p,\rho(g)f)$ (omitting $\rho$ from the notation, think of $(p,gf)$ instead). We'd like to consider those pairs the same (in the quotient). The action that does this service is $((p,f),g)\mapsto (pg,\rho(g^{-1})f)$. In other words, we may operate as if $g$ and $\rho(g^{-1})$ "cancel each other" in the quotient: $[pg,f]=[p,\rho(g)f]$.